# Deletion - Bulk Action - Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to do a bulk action delete.(deleting multiple items at once). Now with my code below, the selected items are  deleted but  it  still returns `alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');`  Why is that happening?

**HTML**

```
    <button style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="btn delete_all" data-url="{{ url('item/deleteAll') }}">Delete All Selected</button> 



 <tbody>
    @foreach($items as $item)
    <tr id="{{$item->id}}" >
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="{{$item->id}}"></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.5/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#master').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
         {
            $(".sub_chk").prop('checked', true);  
         } else {  
            $(".sub_chk").prop('checked',false);  
         }  
        });

        $('.delete_all').on('click', function(e) {

            var allVals = [];  
            $(".sub_chk:checked").each(function() {  
                allVals.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
            });  

            if(allVals.length <=0)  
            {  
                alert("Please select row.");  
            } 

            else {  

                var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?");  
                if(check == true){  

                    var join_selected_values = allVals.join(","); 

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).data('url'),
                        type: 'GET',
                        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        data: 'ids='+join_selected_values,

                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data['success']) 
                            {
                                $("#" + data['tr']).slideUp("slow");
                                alert(data['success']);
                            } 
                            else if (data['error']) 
                            {
                                alert(data['error']);
                            } 
                            else 
                            {   //this is where the issue is
                                alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert(data.responseText);
                        }
                    });

                  $.each(allVals, function( index, value ) 
                  {
                      $('table tr').filter("[data-row-id='" + value + "']").remove();
                  });
                }  
            }  
        });

        $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
            rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
            onConfirm: function (event, element) {
                element.trigger('confirm');
            }
        });

        $(document).on('confirm', function (e) {
            var ele = e.target;
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: ele.href,
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['success']) 
                    {
                        $("#" + data['tr']).slideUp("slow");
                        alert(data['success']);
                    } 
                    else if (data['error']) {
                        alert(data['error']);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.responseText);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('item/deleteAll','controller@deleteAll');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function deleteAll(Request $request)
     {
         $ids = $request->ids; 
         DB::table("items")->whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->delete(); 
         return redirect('item/all')->with('status','Items Successfully deleted!');

     }
```

Comment: Edit: You hardcoded the error alert; never mind the explanation. Can you find the log entry for what actually happened? You can find it in `storage/logs/laravel.log`; hard to debug any issue without the specific error, so find it and add it to your question.

Comment: Check the log files for error message

Comment: Did you check if ajax call was successful? I see you're alerting "Whoops Something went wrong" if call was successful, but response data is something unexpected.

Comment: @TimLewis, i just checked the log file and there is no error related to what i have in the question

Comment: @woopata, i dont get you please

Comment: Check Oleg's answer below. Your controller method doesn't return any data. But your javascript, specifically success part of the ajax call expects either 'success' data (first if) or 'error' data (second if). There's third option, which handles situation when data wasn't provided. In that case your code will make an alert 'Whoops Something went wrong!!'. You even have comment there "//this is where the issue is"

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an ajax call, you should return something like

```
return ['success' => 1];
```

From you Controller, not the redirect.

An example:

```
    public function deleteAll(Request $request)
{
    $ids = $request->ids;
    DB::table("items")->whereIn('id',explode(",",$ids))->delete();

    if(request()->ajax()) {
        return ['success' => 1];
    }

    return redirect('item/all')->with('status','Items Successfully deleted!');
}
```

Comment: it returns this line `return ['success' => 1]` but not this `    return redirect('item/all')->with('status','Items Successfully deleted!');`.. why is that please?  The page doesn't redirect
`

Comment: because you expect it in your ajax call:  success: function (data) {                   if (data['success'])

Comment: How can i fix this ? to make this line `return redirect('item/all')->with('status','Items Successfully deleted!');`  run 
`

Comment: Why would you need is since you make an AJAX call?

Comment: Because i need to refresh the page so the user can instantly see the deleted items.

Comment: Delete them through jQuery then, or make a usual form instead of ajax call.